# Macbook Pro on Yosemite - screen going to black

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

I have a fresh install of OS X Yosemite. There is an issue where the screen goes black or seems to go to sleep while I am using it. When this happens, it's iffy on getting it come back on. The <kbd>esc</kbd> key works sometimes. Closing the lid and logging in works too. I have three console copy and paste of the times this event is happening in the hopes that someone can help me troubleshoot. I thought maybe it was my DNS servers so I added Google DNS, but not sure this is it.

[Here](http://dharmadogpictures.com/tmp/LOGSAPPLEMAC.rtf) is my two logs from my console which should be very helpful in diganosing.

Comment: What model do you have?

Answer (score 1):

That log shows few problems.

First you have continuous Crash `ReportCrash[2551]: Saved crash report for mdworker32[2550] version 917.1 to /Users/TARINISHOME/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mdworker32_2015-04-03-123458_Tarinis-MacBook-Pro.crash`

That is the

> mdworker32 is the 32 bit version metadata server worker process.
>   mdworker is used by mds to scan and index files as a volume is mounted
>   or a file changes.

So tell us what is connected to your system and Open that Crash report to look what is happening.

I would also (temporary) disable any sharing.

Comment: Hello Buscar there is nothing connected to the system. Its a laptop nothing is connected no usb no sharing at all. Only programs that are open are microsoft word 2011 and firefox. thats it.. So does mdworker32 have anything to do with Word?

Comment: It is showing the Netgear32 PCI card? why is that?. It is a 32 bit type which would have problems with Yosemite. Also your frequent error is "CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x92a6d000): p=3382[mdworker32] ..." resulting in Crash Report.

Comment: The only think I can think of is the Netgear is the modem that is currently at the rental Im renting... They have a netgear  modem. I have no PCI card attached or installed that I can think of. Currently its possible that Installed the Cuda Nivida driver on this machine and was the culprit for the black screen. So far I have deleted the Cuda driver and its not doing it but still testing.